# List of all changes from word1 to word2 (via Levenshtein)

Tags: python, list, transformation, cpu-word, levenshtein-distance

Is there a way to show concrete changesteps of a word-transformation? For example:

```
import Levenshtein as leven 

word1 = "man"
word2 = "scotsman"

# desired output
leven.???(word1,word2) = ['sman','tsman','otsman','cotsman','scotsman']
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, could you please mark it as the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will do what you want when the longer string (I called it `haystack` starts or ends with the short string (`needle`). The order of the `word1` and `word2` parameters does not matter.

**N.B.** This function does not work when the needle is in the middle of the string because this could cause other problems (e.g. What to do when the substring occurs multiple times?).

```
word1 = "man"
word2 = "scotsman"

def changeSteps(word1, word2):

    needle = word1 if len(word1) < len(word2) else word2
    haystack = word1 if len(word1) > len(word2) else word2

    if haystack.endswith(needle):
        reverse=True
    else:
        reverse = False

    if needle in haystack:
        difference = haystack.replace(needle, "")

        if reverse:
            difference = ''.join(reversed(difference))
            needle = ''.join(reversed(needle))

        steps = [needle+difference[0:i] for i in range(1,len(difference)+1)]

        if reverse:
            steps = [ ''.join(reversed(s)) for s in steps ]

        return steps

    else:
        return []


print(changeSteps(word1, word2))
```

EDIT: Also beware that, when the string both starts and ends with the `needle` you tell it to look for, the function will calculate the change steps for the *ends with needle* case.